# Visualizing dataframes in ipython/jupyter notebook by using javascript

Tags: javascript, pandas, jupyter-notebook, data-visualization, ipython

I recently discovered that it's quite easy to inject HTML into Jupiter notebook to visualize python objects. That seems particularly useful to me to write a custom interactive plot for pandas dataframes.

The most basic example is:

```
from IPython.display import HTML
import pandas as pd
HTML( pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4]]).to_html() )
# prints the html representation of a dataframe
```

What I am trying to accomplish is something similar to what apache zeppelin implements (https://zeppelin.apache.org/, data visualization), where you can pivot columns interactively to explore the data frame.

The first solution I can think of is writing a function get_html that takes the pandas df as input in a json format and visualizes it via d3, pseudocode:

```
def get_html(json_data):
    big_html = \
    f"""
    <html>
    <script>
    // inject {json_data} into the js library of your choice
    <script>
    </html>
    """
    return big_html
HTML( get_html(df.to_json(orient="records")) )
```

This seems suboptimal for a number of reasons, for instance

1. performance (df are often big)
2. ease of development (get_html should actually call a custom `js` library, instead of embedding js that way)

However, I cannot figure out how to make this work better.
An idea could be dumping the df onto a json and then re-reading from the disk, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: There's some stuff out there that was written already to do something similar to what you describe as the reason for trying this, I think. See [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/two-essential-pandas-add-ons-499c1c9b65de) or [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/interactive-pivot-tables-in-jupyter-notebook-fc74bad8aa67). Some of the things are outdated, like suggesting an exclamation point with `pip` when you should use `%pip ...` now. Plus, I'd use current qgrid documentation for installing it. It's much easier to install extensions in JupyterLab 3 than when that was written.

Comment: Plus [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/mito-a-jupiterlab-extension-for-easy-data-manipulation-with-no-code-57a54a34e65e). Again, consult the current documentation for installation.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not familiar with apache zeppelin, but I’ve had good results with the tools at
[bokeh](https://bokeh.org/) for visual data exploration.
Especially check out the crossfilter example on the demo page. Hope it helps.